# ESLint and lookbehind assertion

Tags: javascript, regex, eslint

I have a regular expression with a lookbehind assertion that ESLint doesn't seem to recognise as valid. However lookahead assertions are fine.

I can reproduce this issue with the latest version of ESLint (I've used the [online demo](https://eslint.org/demo)) and with very simple and contrived examples.

Lookahead assertion: match `b` (and only `b`) if followed by `d`:

```
'bd'.match(/b(?=d)/) //=> ['b']
'be'.match(/b(?=d)/) //=> null
```

ESLint recognises `/b(?=d)/` as valid regular expression:

[image]

Lookbehind assertion: match `b` (and only `b`) if preceded by `a`:

```
'ab'.match(/(?<=a)b/) //=> ['b']
'eb'.match(/(?<=a)b/) //=> null
```

ESLint doesn't recognise `/(?<=a)b/` as a valid regular expression:

[image]

Question: what's wrong with my regular expression that causes ESLint to complain?

---

ESLint configuration used in the demos above:

```json
{
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaVersion": 5,
        "sourceType": "script",
        "ecmaFeatures": {}
    },
    "rules": {
        "constructor-super": 2,
        "for-direction": 2,
        "getter-return": 2,
        "no-async-promise-executor": 2,
        "no-case-declarations": 2,
        "no-class-assign": 2,
        "no-compare-neg-zero": 2,
        "no-cond-assign": 2,
        "no-const-assign": 2,
        "no-constant-condition": 2,
        "no-control-regex": 2,
        "no-debugger": 2,
        "no-delete-var": 2,
        "no-dupe-args": 2,
        "no-dupe-class-members": 2,
        "no-dupe-else-if": 2,
        "no-dupe-keys": 2,
        "no-duplicate-case": 2,
        "no-empty": 2,
        "no-empty-character-class": 2,
        "no-empty-pattern": 2,
        "no-ex-assign": 2,
        "no-extra-boolean-cast": 2,
        "no-extra-semi": 2,
        "no-fallthrough": 2,
        "no-func-assign": 2,
        "no-global-assign": 2,
        "no-import-assign": 2,
        "no-inner-declarations": 2,
        "no-invalid-regexp": 2,
        "no-irregular-whitespace": 2,
        "no-misleading-character-class": 2,
        "no-mixed-spaces-and-tabs": 2,
        "no-new-symbol": 2,
        "no-obj-calls": 2,
        "no-octal": 2,
        "no-prototype-builtins": 2,
        "no-redeclare": 2,
        "no-regex-spaces": 2,
        "no-self-assign": 2,
        "no-setter-return": 2,
        "no-shadow-restricted-names": 2,
        "no-sparse-arrays": 2,
        "no-this-before-super": 2,
        "no-undef": 2,
        "no-unexpected-multiline": 2,
        "no-unreachable": 2,
        "no-unsafe-finally": 2,
        "no-unsafe-negation": 2,
        "no-unused-labels": 2,
        "no-unused-vars": 2,
        "no-useless-catch": 2,
        "no-useless-escape": 2,
        "no-with": 2,
        "require-yield": 2,
        "use-isnan": 2,
        "valid-typeof": 2
    },
    "env": {}
}
```

Comment: It should be at least `"ecmaVersion": 9`, the [default is said](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#specifying-parser-options) to be `5` which is rather old.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can refer to the [*Specifying Parser Options*](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#specifying-parser-options) reference:

> `ecmaVersion` - set to 3, 5 (default), 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, or 12 to specify the version of ECMAScript syntax you want to use. You can also set to 2015 (same as 6), 2016 (same as 7), 2017 (same as 8), 2018 (same as 9), 2019 (same as 10), 2020 (same as 11), or 2021 (same as 12) to use the year-based naming.

As you can see, the  default value is `5`, meaning it only supports ES5. Lookbehinds are [compliant with ECMAScript 2018](https://2ality.com/2017/05/regexp-lookbehind-assertions.html), so you need to make sure you set `ecmaVersion` to at least `9`:

```js
"parserOptions": {
        "ecmaVersion": 9,
        "sourceType": "script",
        "ecmaFeatures": {}
    },
```

Comment: If there a file-by-file comment version for this? Just for fun, I've tried `/* eslint-env es9 */` to mirror `/* eslint-env es6 */` from [the ESLint docs](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/migrating-to-2.0.0#built-in-global-variables) (the `es9` shortcut doesn't seem to exist) and `/* eslint-env ecmaVersion:9 */` just to see if I'd get lucky (I did not). Seems like [`/* eslint-env es2020 */` would nuke it](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#specifying-environments), but I still have the lookbehind regex reported invalid.